# Why are "inner" automorphisms named this way?

Tags: group-theory, soft-question, terminology

Similarly to "*center* of a group", also "*inner* automorphism" has a topological sounding. But, though for the former I could find some possible explanation in this site, for the latter I couldn't. So:

> Why are *inner* automorphisms named this way?

Comment: I wonder if the term "outer automorphism group" was coined first. This would make sense, as outer automorphism groups have been studied since at least the 1920s (e.g. Neilsen proved that the outer automorphism group of a surface group is the extended mapping class group of the surface), while on the other hand, inner automorphism groups are not studied, or at least not to the same extent.

Answer (score 12):

My guess is that it's because they can be defined by a pretty natural operations from *inside the group*. The most basic operation we have is "multiply" (although "invert" is arguably 'more basic', but let me go on...). So we can look at a map like
$$
f_a(x) = a \cdot x
$$
which takes $G$ to $G$ (where $a$ is some fixed element of $G$). This isn't an automorphism, though, because it takes $e$ to $a$ rather than to itself. We could fix this by throwing in a $a^{-1}$, saying
$$
g_a(x) = a^{-1} \cdot (a \cdot x)
$$
but applying associativity reduces that to just the identity map, which is boring. We could, instead, fix the "$e$ goes to the wrong place" situation by multiplying by $a^{-1}$ on the *other side*:
$$
h_a(x) = (a \cdot x)\cdot a^{-1},
$$
and that (at least for non-abelian groups) defines an automorphism, entirely using stuff from "inside $G$", so it's reasonable to call it an "inner automorphism."

To return to my original remark, "inversion" is pretty basic as well, so we could try 
$$
u(x) = x^{-1}
$$
as a possible "internal automorphism". It certainly is "internal", and it even has $u(e) = e$, so we're ahead of the game. But when we look at 
$$
u(ab) = (ab)^{-1} = b^{-1}a^{-1} = u(b) u(a)
$$
we see that unless the group is abelian, it's not a homorphism.

So for abelian groups, there's one "internally generated" automorphism (inversion) that jumps out at us, together with the identity automorphism. For *non*-abelian groups, there's a whole family of "internally generated" automorphisms (those defined via conjugation), among which is the identity (defined by conjugation by the identity element, for instance). Of course this "whole family" may contain only a few elements (i.e., many inner automorphisms may turn out to be the
same).

I don't *know* that this is where the term "inner" came from, but it sure seems reasonable.

Comment: I have seen them denoted as $\textrm{Int}(G)$, though I forget if this was standing for internal or intrinsic etc.  Either way it emphasizes the viewpoint that they are automorphisms naturally obtained from $G$ itself.

Answer (score 11):

I looked in some early sources and I think I have found the definitive answer.  I'll give the short summary first, but it may be hard to appreciate without the historical context.  Please suspend your disbelief while you read this; I promise to explain.

> Suppose $\varphi$ is an automorphism of $G$.  There **always** exists an element $s$ that allows us to write $\varphi$ in the form $g\mapsto s^{-1}gs$.  Then $\varphi$ is called an *inner* or an *outer* automorphism according to whether $s$ is in $G$ or out of $G$.

Now I should explain the strange claim that such $s$ exists even for an outer automorphism.  The claim is not actually incorrect, but only old-fashioned.

You need to understand that until at least the 1930s, the study of group theory was much less abstract than it is today.  Typically, a group was *not* considered to be a set equipped with an arbitrary binary operation, etc. Rather:

> Groups were understood to be *groups of permutations*.

The term “group” itself was understood as an abbreviation of the phrase “group of permutations”, and the crucial property was *closure*.

In the modern view, the idea of taking two completely arbitrary groups $G$ and $H$ and forming $G\cap H$ is nonsense, or at least confused, because the two group operations are not necessarily the same, and indeed $G$ and $H$ may not have the same identity element, or any elements in common.  But up through the early 20th century, $G\cap H$ was perfectly clear: $G$  and $H$ have the same operation, because the operation is composition of permutations, and $G$ and $H$ have the same identity element, because in both cases it is the identity permutation.

(Viewed in this way, Cayley's theorem is a great deal more obvious than in a modern presentation!)

With that context established, here is the relevant paragraph from the earliest source I could find, Harold Hilton, [*An Introduction to the Theory of Groups of Finite Order*](https://www.google.com/books/edition/An_Introduction_to_the_Theory_of_Groups/YRwPAAAAIAAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=%22inner+automorphism%22&pg=PA136&printsec=frontcover), Clarendon Press 1908:

> A simple isomorphism of $G$ with itself is often called an *automorphism* of $G$.  It is defined as an *inner* or *cogredient* automorphism, if the isomorphism can be obtained by transforming $G$ by an element contained in $G$; if not as an *outer* or *contragredient* automorphism.

The key point is implicit, so it is easy to miss.  But here it is:  we can still understand an automorphism $\varphi$ as being a “transformation” of $G$ — that is, as a mapping $g \mapsto s^{-1}gs$ — even when $s$ is not an element of $G$.

To take the simplest possible example, consider $A_3 = \{(), (1\ 2\ 3), (1\ 3\ 2)\}$. There is an obvious nontrivial automorphism $\varphi$, which is clearly outer.  In 2021, we would say that $\varphi$ does not have the form $g\mapsto s^{-1}gs$.  But this is not quite true!  It *is* true that there is no such $s$ **in $A_3$**.   But if we remember to think like an early group theorist, we view  $A_3$ as always being a subgroup of $S_3$. Now let $s = (2\ 3)$ and see that $\varphi$ does in fact map each $g$ to $s^{-1}gs$.

It's not hard to see that such an $s$ must exist for any automorphism of $G$, if one is prepared to construe $G$ as a subgroup of a larger symmetric group.  (Cayley's theorem again.)

Comment: Nice answer! However, I'm not sure the claim that "Groups were always understood to be groups of permutations" is correct. For example, in the 1910s Dehn was using presentations to study fundamental groups of surfaces, while von Dyck in the 1880s used presentations also.

Comment: You're right, I used the wrong quantifier.  I will try to correct my phrasing.  Thanks!

Comment: No problem (maybe the quantifier is "finite"?). Also, have you looked in Burnside's book? It precedes Hilton's book.

Comment: Yes, I have spent quite a lot of time reading Burnside's book, which was how I came to understand the early view of group theory in the first place. But I didn't have a copy handy and I wasn't sure it used the required terminology, so I just did Google book search to see what I could find out.

Comment: This viewpoint is a little difficult though. There is no element of any symmetric group that acts as the outer automorphism of $S_6$. You have to replace $S_6$ by an isomorphic copy in some larger symmetric group in order for this to occur.

Comment: Yes, you have to embed it in the holomorph.  But the holomorph itself was a much simpler idea in 1908: it's essentially $G\cup Aut(G)$.  In modern group theory the two sets have different types of elements, but in 1908 there is no problem.

Comment: I looked to see what Burnside had to say about it.  (It's Burnside, _Theory of Groups of Finite Order_, 2 ed. Cambridge University Press, 1911) and it is not much different: “An isomorphism of a group, which is thus formed [by conjugating] the operations of the group by one of themselves, is called an _inner_ isomorphism.  All others are called _outer_ isomorphisms.”  Again it's clear that Burnside considers $s^{-1}gs$ to be sensible even when $s\notin G$. (§63, p.84)

Comment: I'm no expert on the history of group theory, but I think some of the claims here are overstated. For example, even when "group" mostly meant "permutation group", I'm not sure that people would have been happy to take intersection of arbitary groups. What about permutation groups with different ground sets, for example? They were definitely considering such things.

Comment: Another example: embedding a group in a different group seems obvious when we are dealing with abstract groups, but if permutation group is the core concept, then something like the degree is an invariant of the group itself, and a different embedding is really a different group. (One could still recognise they are isomorphic of course.) This is relevant to the problem at hand for the reason David Craven pointed out.

Comment: I should also add that "$G$ and $Aut(G)$ are naturally part of the same group" is not true for every permutation group $G$! It is true for various permutation groups, including regular groups, but not for the natural copy of $S_6$, as David pointed out. (Finally, small nitpick: the holomorph should be $\langle G,Aut(G)\rangle$, not $G\cup Aut(G)$.)

Answer (score 1):

No more than a guess. Every $G$ realizes via left and right multiplication maps by a fixed $a\in G$, say $\lambda_a,\rho_a\in\operatorname{Sym}(G)$ respectively, with $a$ ranging throughout $G$. In a sense, $G$ as a group "is" the pair $(\Lambda,R)$, where $\Lambda:=\{\lambda_a, a\in G\}$ and $R:=\{\rho_a, a\in G\}$ are subgroups of $\operatorname{Sym}(G)$. Now, we can think of "$G$ in $\operatorname{Sym}(G)$" as the subgroup $\Lambda R(=R\Lambda)\le\operatorname{Sym}(G)$. It turns out that:

$$\operatorname{Aut}(G)\cap \Lambda R=\{\lambda_a\rho_{a^{-1}},a\in G\}\tag 1$$

Therefore, the RHS of $(1)$ comprises all and only the automorphisms of $G$ which lie *inside* "$G$ in $\operatorname{Sym}(G)$" (namely $\Lambda R$), which then can be rightly said *"inner automorphisms"*.

Answer (score 0):

Like the other answerers, I can only conjecture, but I would say this.

Given a group $G$, there is always some larger group $G'$ containing $G$ as a normal subgroup and having the property that *every* automorphism of $G$ is induced by conjugation by a suitable element of $a \in G'$. In that case, the automorphism of $G$ is "inner" if and only if $a$ can be selected to be in $G$ itself.

An example of such a group $G'$, in which all automorphisms of $G$ can be obtained by conjugation, would be the semidirect product $G \rtimes \text{Aut}(G)$